# What is the "pasuq" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

What is the purpose of [pasuq](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pasuq)?

A *pasuk* is not strictly a unit of meaning, and it seems that a class of questions that would be categorized by the unit of punctuation it does represent is highly technical and not likely forthcoming. I question whether [the only questioned to be tagged as such](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/why-is-said-after-s) to date falls into this ostensible category as well.

Comment: Re the only question so far thus tagged: Well, it _is_ about a _pasuk_.

Comment: @msh210 But is it about a _pasuk qua pasuk_ or the contents of that _pasuk_, which is incidentally offset by two _p'siki_?

Comment: I have found that on new sites, people tend to dump any possible relevant word into the tags box, starting from copying the question title to including any vaguely relevant word. E.g. on SO there is a tag "starts-with" - what possible value does that have as a tag? It's important to catch these value-less tags early, good work on grabbing this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with your concern and have merged it without synonym into [tanach-scripture-bible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanach-scripture-bible).